# Django, нужна кастомная аналитика, аналог Яндекс Метрики

Tags: django

Есть онлайн магазин на Джанго.
Надо добавить к нему аналитику по посетителям (браузер, устройство, источник...). Какой-нибудь аналог Яндекс Метрики. По некоторым причинам Яндекс Метрика и Google не подходят.
Может есть какое-нибудь готовое решение?

Comment: Федеральный закон "О персональных данных" от 27.07.2006 N 152-ФЗ. разрешение уже получено ?

Comment: Там достаточно указать "Пользуясь сайтом Вы соглашаетесь с *****" вроде как. По вопросу - нет, не встречал. Но если погуглить, то можно найти JS скрипт который получает информацию о пользователе (Браузер, скорость инета и тд (нужно было выяснить почему  у людей не работает что либо))

Comment: https://59.rkn.gov.ru/directions/p18637   а за простое 'вы согласились' можно попасть на штрафы. лучше делайте по закону.

Comment: самому писать и на гитхаб кидать